# Calculate sum per month in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a dataset of some people who frequently gives a charitable organisation, i am trying to calculate the sum of new donors minus the sum of donors who cancel their "subscription". Some people have not ended their subscription, and therefore have NA in the EndDate column. The data is structured like this:

```
Contact-ID      StartDate       EndDate
 1              2021-09-01      2021-10-01
 2              2021-09-01      2021-10-01
 3              2021-10-01  
 4              2021-10-01      2021-11-01
```

From this there is two outputs I am looking for. One would be a table which would look something like this:

```
2021-09         2
2021-10         0
2021-11        -1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```r
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  mutate(across(StartDate:EndDate, as.Date)) %>%
  summarize(Month = seq(as.Date('2021-09-01'), as.Date('2021-11-01'), 
                        by = 'month'),
            users = sapply(Month, function(x) sum(StartDate <= x & 
                                              (EndDate > x | is.na(EndDate))))
  )

#>        Month users
#> 1 2021-09-01     2
#> 2 2021-10-01     2
#> 3 2021-11-01     1
```